# Simple python conditional statement shortcut syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I am having trouble understanding the shorthand conditional statement in the python below.

```
def number(number):
    return number or number == 3

print number("")
```

What does this shortcut syntax mean? Is it the same as the following?

```
def number(number):
    if number or number == 3:
        return number

print number("")
```

The first prints False and the latter None (I believe None means the syntax is not valid?).

Comment: If there are differences in the return value, it obviously isn't the same.

Comment: number == 3 doesn't make sense in the logic.

Comment: First function return True or False. Second function returns number or None.

Answer (score 4):

The conditional statement is a bit pointless in this case (except for some very strange cases like overwriting the equals/integer/boolean values of `number`).

Basically what you are doing right now is like this:

```
def number(number):
    if number:
        return number
    else:
        return number == 3
```

If there would be an `and` it would be useful, right now it's pointless.

The or can be useful like this:

```
return spam or eggs
```

If spam is not null it will return spam, otherwise it will return eggs.

Illustration btw:

```
>>> for number in range(5):                       
...     print 'number', number, number or number == 3
number 0 False
number 1 1
number 2 2
number 3 3
number 4 4
```

Long version of `number and number == 3 or 5`

```
def number(number):
    if number and number == 3:
        return 3
    else:
        return 5
```

The `spam and spam.eggs` thing is useful because if `spam` would be `None` it wouldn't execute the `spam.eggs` part which would normally give an `AttributeError`.

Comment: what would be the long hand equivalent of `return number and number == 3`?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant expression in both cases is `number or number == 3`.

Python splits this expression into 2 parts: `(number) or (number == 3)`
It evaluates the individual parts first, and then evaluates the results with `or`.

So we have `""` (treated as `False`) `or` `"" == 3` (which *evaluates* to `False`).
This *becomes* `"" or False`. Since both expressions are `False`-y, this entire expression evaluates to `False`.

In the first function, you return the value of the expression, which is `False`.
In the second function, you only return the value of the expression if it is true. If it's false, you don't return anything.

In python, a function which doesn't return anything returns `None` by default.

Comment: you taught a man to fish, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `number` is valued to `True` (So, not `0` or `None`), the function just returns the number.

If the number is valued to `False`, the function will return `number == 3` (So `True` if it's 3, `False` else)

As the latter will *always* return False (If `number == 3`, then the function would have returned 3 in the first case), it could be shortened down to:

`return number or False`
Which will return the number if it's not 0 or None, else it will return False.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how Python evaluates expressions and objects.

Your first example:

You send in a empty string `""`, this to Python is `False`, much like an empty list (`[]`).

```
def number(number):
    # so this will now be (False) or (number == 3) but since the first 
    # expression was False it will not evaluate the number comparison and thusly
    # return False
    return number or number == 3

print number("")
```

Your second example is a otherwise.
You have an explicit `if` stating that if numbers evaluate to `True` ie. not empty or numbers are equal to `3` enter the following block and return from it.

But since you supply an empty string, which we just learned returns False, it will by pass the if and return the default value for any Python function, `None`.

```
def number(number):
    if number or number == 3:
        return number
    #default says return None here.

print number("")
```